# Error while Launching activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Обновил Android Studio, начались странные вещи. Запускаю проект - вылетает ошибка:

```
04/09 15:14:22: Launching app
$ adb push D:\ASprojects\InnovationBeer\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/eu.innovationpassport.innovationbeer
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/eu.innovationpassport.innovationbeer"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/eu.innovationpassport.innovationbeer
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "eu.innovationpassport.innovationbeer/eu.innovationpassport.innovationbeer.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "eu.innovationpassport.innovationbeer/eu.innovationpassport.innovationbeer.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while Launching activity
```

Самое интересное, что программа работает, если долго пробовать запустить - на 20+ раз работает. Старое приложение закрываю, иногда даже не помогает перезагрузка телефона и Android Studio.

Comment: Как я понимаю, вышла уже: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Run> Edit Configurations > слева Android Application,app > Справа Launch Options > Launch: Выбрать Default Activity.
Это мне помогло

Comment: Это не ответ, а просто ваш сброс эмоций, не несущий полезной информации...

Comment: @Harry, это крик души)

Answer (score 0):

Была аналогичная проблема только для Сервиса, день убил на решение, начало весь гугл говорил про проблемы с манифестом. решение указанное выше решило проблему полностью.
**Run> Edit Configurations > слева Android Application,app > Справа Launch Options > Launch: Выбрать Default Activity**.